# How To Capture ISP Name?

Tags: javascript, salesforce, ip-address, apex-code, visualforce

How do I capture the user's ISP name in Salesforce.com? The solution can be in JavaScript of in Salesforce.com such as Apex/VisualForce Pages.

Example of a website which captures the user's ISP name is: http://whatismyipaddress.com/

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to query a GeoLocation provider database that has the ISP provider information.

Here is a list of providers listed on the page you've linked in your question: http://whatismyipaddress.com/geolocation-providers

They usually require you to pay, and will probably provide you with samples of how to query their databases.

I'm unaware of any free geolocation databases that provide ISP information.