# Can you detect a user's ISP provider with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have static webpage. In that page I want to get the ISP provider & location of a user, using JavaScript.

Is there any way to do this using only JavaScript, or will I need to use other tools to do so?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9289439/how-to-capture-isp-name

Comment: With only a static webpage (and no third-party services) you wouldn't be able to get the IP of the user using Javascript (so that you can find their location/ISP), as far as I know.  Someone correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's **not** possible to detect the ISP provider **using only** JavaScript, if you would be willing to use PHP however, it's very simple:

```
<?php 
  $hostname = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']); 
  echo $hostname; 
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

you can call http://ip-api.com/json by a Get http request and the response is a json containing user's IP data including "isp"

Answer (score 0):

You can get the geo location using [geo location API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W3C_Geolocation_API). I don't think it is possible to get the ISP using JavaScript on the client.

Comment: Is there any possibility without using third party API to get ISP??

Comment: I don't think so. How should this even work? Do you want the browser to know what your ISP is and return it in some JavaScript API?